# TestCafe: How can I control the order of test execution

Tags: testcafe

I'm running a TestCafe test suite with three tests. To simplify, it's:

```js
fixture`Cover Page tests`
.page(getUrl())
test('Test 1...)
test('Test 2...)
test('Test 3...)
```

I want "Test 1" to run first so that I can do some setup with the `test.before(...)` hook but TestCafe always runs "Test 3" first.

Is there any way to force the order of the tests to follow the order of definition?

TestCafe version 2.1.0

Comment: which version of testcafe are you on? I tried in 1.19.0 and 1.20.1.  It runs the tests in the same order in which I have them in fixture.

Comment: @Janaaaa Version 2.1.0 -- added to the description.

Comment: I could not recreate the issue in 2.1.0.  Does the simplified example you provided closely mimic the structure of your tests?  also, please check if this is relevant in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63344836/running-testcafe-tests-in-sequence-with-html-reports?rq=3

Comment: Thanks... problem was running them in parallel in our pipeline; the work in sequence locally.